# creating an audio compiler in flutter, using recording process to create an audio file

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

I am developing a flutter app that lets the user play a certain sound to make a beat. I want to record the audio the user play's within the app without using the microphone. When using the microphone, the audio quality decreases and additional unwanted sound gets into the audio.

My current process for recording and playing back the audio created by the user is, I create a data list of the sound the user clicked on and the time it was clicked on as a method of recording and I run those data back to play the sound.

This has been working so far, But the issue with this approach is that I can't generate the audio file out of those data. so I am looking for a way to capture the audio while the user is playing or for a way to generate the audio file from the data list already created.

Any tip on how to approach this would be helpful, even if it is a completely different way of doing this.

And Thanks ahead